# what is the meaning of first {} curly brace in mongodb projection query

Tags: mongodb

I want to know what is the need of first curly brace `{}` after find here in this query.

```
db.mycol.find({},{"title":1,_id:0})
```

Answer (score 6):

It is an empty query, in the sense of a limiting boundary. So

```
db.mycol.find({},{"title":1,_id:0})
```

would basically translate to

> Show me the title, but not the _id (as you would do by default) for all documents of the mycol collection in the current database.

Let's say you want all the titles written by Alan Turing. So you could modify the query part like this:

```
db.mycol.find({"author":"Alan Turing"},{"title":1,_id:0})
```

In general, MongoDB's find operation can be described like this

```
db.collection.find(query,projection)
```

For more detailed information, you might want to read [find's documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find).

Answer (score 3):

The first Curly braces is used as a `where` condition in **MySql**

Check out this Link - [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)

**MySQL**

```
SELECT user_id, status FROM users WHERE status = "A"
```

**MongoDB**

```
db.users.find(
    { status: "A" },
    { user_id: 1, status: 1, _id: 0 }
)
```

Comment: How is it different from my answer?

Comment: yours is completely opposite

Comment: Can you explain how is it completely different?

Comment: you said first {} is used to "tell which fields to show" we said it is used to  "tell retrieve either all rows with {} or where the condition matches {author:"James"}" i.e where author = james

Comment: Ah, finally I understood. Sorry my bad. I misinterpret the question `first curly brace {} after find here` in the way the the person is asking the what means the first {} after the find (first braces). It was so obvious to me what is the first one, that I thought that he is asking about the second brace. One more time sorry.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Don't worry, we all do mistake sometime. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is called [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) and tells which fields to show. For example here you show only `title`. It is something like `Select title from mycol;` If you will not specify projection it will return everything, which is close to `select * from mycol;`

`_id` is always shown, unless you hide it explicitly with `_id: 0`. Another thing is that you can not mix 0 and 1 (except for `_id`). But one more time - [read FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Answer (score 0):

You should refer this link for better explanation 
    http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

first of all, projection does not return the first result it finds it tells mongo what to return.

.findOne(query) will LIMIT result to one or find(query).limit(1) will also do the same.

You say you are trying to "get all" your data.

a standard find type query will get your started...

```
find({mongo:query},{mongo:projection})
```

but limits results to a cursor from the mongo shell*